# Buscar palabra o patrón dentro de una lista usando fnmatch.filter()

Tags: python

**El problema:** comparar `"guinea"` con `"GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)"` y conseguir que hay match ya que `"guinea"` esta contenida en la segunda frase.

Para ello pretendo usar la función: `fnmatch.filter()`

**Notas:**

- **`fnmatch`** recibe `arg1` = lista, `arg2` = string o directorio .
- Como **`fnmatch`** solo recibe una lista y no le puedo pasar el string con `"GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)"` metí dicho string en una lista.
- Como **`fnmatch`** solo me devuelve una lista con los matchs y no se puedo evaluar directamente si es `True` o `False`  es decir:

  ```
  if fnmatch.filter(i,"*guinea*")== True:
     return True
  else:
     return False
  ```

  tengo la lista: `i = ["GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)","1", "2"]`, 
  donde `"1"` y `"2"` son elemento completamente descartables ya que jamás van a hacer match con mi patrón.

Cree la siguiente función:

```py
        i=["GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)","1", "2"]
        j="guinea"
        print("Buscando j: "+ str(j)+" en i: "+ str(i))
        evaluador=fnmatch.filter(i,"*guinea*")
        print(evaluador)
        print(len(evaluador))
        if len(evaluador)>0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

cuyo resultado es:

> ```
> Buscando j: guinea en i: ['GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)', '1', '2']
> ['GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)']
> 1
> True
> ```

y esto funciona **pero no resuelve mi problema...**,  ya que lo que realmente requiero es que **`fnmatch`** reciba en su segundo argumento una variable ya que necesito que esta función este dentro de un **`for`** y evalúe muchos valores de una lista.

tal que función 2:

```py
Lista1=["GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)","CUENTO", " CUENTO 2"]
Lista2=["guinea", 2]
for i in Lista1:
    for j in Lista2:
        print("Buscando j: "+ str(j)+" en i: "+ str(i))
        match='"*'+str(j)+'*"'
        print(match)
        evaluador=fnmatch.filter(i,str(match))
        print(evaluador)
        print(len(evaluador))
        if len(evaluador)>0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

cuyo resultado es:

> ```
> Buscando j: guinea en i: GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)
> "*guinea*"
> []
> 0
> False
> Buscando j: 2 en i: GUINEA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)
> "*2*"
> []
> 0
> False
> Buscando j: guinea en i: CUENTO
> "*guinea*"
> []
> 0
> False
> Buscando j: 2 en i: CUENTO
> "*2*"
> []
> 0
> False
> Buscando j: guinea en i:  CUENTO 2
> "*guinea*"
> []
> 0
> False
> Buscando j: 2 en i:  CUENTO 2
> "*2*"
> []
> 0
> False
> None
> ```

donde esperaría como resultado 2 matchs, uno con `"guinea"` y uno con `"2"`, pero no funciona.

Comment: alguine que me ayude a agregar la etiqueta  fnmatch  por favor...

Comment: Como tu misma comenta el primer argumento ha de ser un iterable con las cadenas, no la cadena en si misma (esto iteraría sobre los caracteres), es decir `evaluador=fnmatch.filter([i], match)`. No obstante el `return` tal como lo tienes implica que retorna `True` o `False` en la primera iteración... No me queda muy claro que salida esperas obtener al final para ese ejemplo.

Comment: @FJSevilla hola , tienes razon en ~ [i]~, error al plantearlo como ~FOR~ anidado, use la misma letra, sin embargo al probar tu propuesta ~ [i]~ tampoco funciona, creo que ~match~  no esta pasando el valor que tiene en la forma string que necesita ~_fnmatchs_ ~;  en cuanto a que espero como resultado o ~return~, en realidad esto no retornaria nada lo que me intereza es entrar en el ~IF~ cuando hay match para llamar a una funcion, conectar a una base de datos y escribir un valor; ojo Lista1 y Lista2 tambien son Fields de base de datos con cientos de valores...

Comment: Perdón se me pasó comentarlo, las comillas anidadas sobran, haz `match = f'*{j}*'` o `match = "*{}*".format(j)` si usas Python < 3.6. Por cierto, para ver si una lista no está vacía no necesitas `len` para nada en realidad, basta con `if evaluador:`

Comment: gracias funciona, me puedes orientar encuanto a las diferencias entre match = f'*{j}*'  y  match='"*'+str(j)+'*"'  , que hace esa f ?

Comment: @FJSevilla, comprendo, aplicare tu recommendation  ~ if evaluador:  ~ tambien thnx